# Automatically add svn:needs-lock

Tags: svn, svn-propset

Hi I was wondering if there is a way for the SVN server to automatically assign the svn:needs-lock property on any file that is binary and not textual.

We have a rather small developers team but resting on everyone to remember to set this property on newly created binary files doesn't make sense since it's very easy to forget such a thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit the svn config file and add an entry for auto props or use `svn:auto-props` versioned property with SVN 1.8 and newer clients. [Read SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto)!

**EDIT:**

From SVN 1.8 the you can apply the `svn:auto-props` property to the root path of your repository. See this [release note](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config) and updated [SVNBook 1.8 chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto).

Comment: Beware! You have to configure auto props on each SVN client individually. There's no way to have the server automatically apply needs-lock, at least as of svn 1.7.

Comment: TSVN has the tsvn:auto-props property which is used for this: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-tsvn-props

Comment: @Dan but you could create a pre-commit script which rejects binary files that don't have this property.

Answer (score 23):

Apache Subversion 1.8 introduced the [Repository Dictated Configuration](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config) feature which requires **SVN 1.8 client**, but 1.8 server is not necessary because this is a client-side feature.

With Subversion 1.8, you can configure auto-props patterns within a repository using the new Subversion [`svn:auto-props` inherited property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.inheritable).

For example, set `svn:auto-props` value to `*.exe = svn:needs-lock=*` property on the root of your repository (or repository path that represents a root of a project). This will result into *each newly added* *.exe file having `svn:needs-lock=*` property applied.

You can store multi-line values in Subversion properties, so you can add the following standard svn:needs-lock and MIME pattern to `svn:auto-props`:

```
*.bmp = svn:mime-type=image/bmp;svn:needs-lock=*
*.gif = svn:mime-type=image/gif;svn:needs-lock=*
*.ico = svn:mime-type=image/x-icon;svn:needs-lock=*
*.jpeg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg;svn:needs-lock=*
*.jpg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg;svn:needs-lock=*
*.png = svn:mime-type=image/png;svn:needs-lock=*
*.tif = svn:mime-type=image/tiff;svn:needs-lock=*
*.tiff = svn:mime-type=image/tiff;svn:needs-lock=*    
*.doc = svn:mime-type=application/x-msword;svn:needs-lock=*
*.docx = svn:mime-type=application/x-msword;svn:needs-lock=*
*.jar = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odc = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odf = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odg = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odi = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odp = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation;svn:needs-lock=*
*.ods = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odt = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;svn:needs-lock=*
*.pdf = svn:mime-type=application/pdf;svn:needs-lock=*
*.ppt = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.ms-powerpoint;svn:needs-lock=*
*.ser = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream;svn:needs-lock=*
*.swf = svn:mime-type=application/x-shockwave-flash;svn:needs-lock=*
*.vsd = svn:mime-type=application/x-visio;svn:needs-lock=*
*.xls = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.ms-excel;svn:needs-lock=*
*.zip = svn:mime-type=application/zip;svn:needs-lock=*
```

Comment: If * is a wildcard, would * = svn:needs-lock=* work if you wanted to simply apply needs-lock to ALL file types?

Comment: @JonathonCowley I've tested it right now with TortoiseSVN 1.8.7 (SVN 1.8.9) and setting `svn:auto-props` to `* = svn:needs-lock=*` does exactly what you ask about, i.e. "applies" needs-lock to all files under the folder where you set the property.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast response.  I'd have tested it myself, but I'm on a PC where I don't have access to Subversion.

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that the auto props method has to be configured on each SVN client being used.  So when you're setting up a new developer, or an existing developer on a new machine, you have to remember to perform this configuration.

If you are all using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), you can set the [tsvn:autoprops](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-auto-props) property on the base folder of each checkout and it will be honoured by all TortoiseSVN clients.

If you really want to nail it, you'll need to put a [pre-commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) hook in each repository.  The [enforcer](http://svn.collab.net/viewvc/svn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/enforcer/) script might be easily tooled for this.

If you have any python-fu, [RepoGuard](http://repoguard.tigris.org/) (the successor to [SVNChecker](http://svnchecker.tigris.org/)) looks like it could be useful too.

No matter which you pick, there's no way to retroactively apply the property to existing files in the repository, I think.  You can probably enforce it on the next commit of the file, however.

Comment: This is an excellent point.  If you're used to server-side enforcement of this (such as in TFS), it's not immediately apparent.  +1

Comment: Outdated, as well. See "Repository Dictated Configuration" feature of SVN 1.8: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config

Answer (score 2):

There's a page on this Subversion wiki that describes all the different options on how to automatically add needs-lock and how to guarantee it has been set. The page also gives example scripts and configuration details:

http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Automatic_lock-modify-unlock

Comment: Note that there's no way to have the server automatically apply needs-lock. This documentation explains how to configure each SVN client individually to apply needs-lock automatically, and how to configure the SVN server to reject commits that don't use needs-lock correctly.

Comment: @DanFabulich now there is way do instruct SVN 1.8 client to apply auto-props from repository.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pre-commit hook

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv

SVNLOOKOK=1

# Check files for svn:needs-lock property
# Exit on all errors.
set -e

echo "`$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS"`" | while read REPOS_PATH
do
 if [[ $REPOS_PATH =~ (A|M|U)[[:blank:]]{3}(.*)\.(.*) ]]
 then
  if [ ${#BASH_REMATCH[*]} -ge 2 ]
    then
  FILENAME=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.${BASH_REMATCH[3]};

  # Make sure every file has the svn:needs-lock property set
   if [ "" == "`$SVNLOOK propget -t \"$TXN\" \"$REPOS\" svn:needs-lock \"$FILENAME\" 2> /dev/null`" ]
    then
    ERROR=1;
    echo "" >&2
    echo "svn:needs-lock property has to be set on \"$FILENAME\"" >&2
    echo "" >&2
   fi
  fi
 fi
 test -z $ERROR || (exit 1)
done

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

and a pre-lock hook

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOS="$1"
PATH="$2"
USER="$3"

# If a lock exists and is owned by a different person, don't allow it
# to be stolen (e.g., with 'svn lock --force ...').

# (Maybe this script could send email to the lock owner?)
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
GREP=/bin/grep
SED=/bin/sed

LOCK_OWNER=`$SVNLOOK lock "$REPOS" "$PATH" | \
            $GREP '^Owner: ' | $SED 's/Owner: //'`

# If we get no result from svnlook, there's no lock, allow the lock to
# happen:
if [ "$LOCK_OWNER" = "" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# If the person locking matches the lock's owner, allow the lock to
# happen:
if [ "$LOCK_OWNER" = "$USER" ]; then
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Nice! I adapted the `pre-commit` hook to print out the `svn propset` command with the needed files: https://gist.github.com/spl/0affe6cc0e06aae6cb46a45b8a9edd36