# SVN auto property based on repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversion-edge

We have multiple SVN repositories. A developer may be working on multiple repositories at the same time. I am aware of the auto-prop option available with SVN. If we enable this, it is adding the property on files in all the repositories whenever commit happens. Is there any way   I can tell subversion to enable auto-prop only when checkin happens to a particular repository and not all the repos.

I am adding the property 'needs-lock'. There are hundreds of developers working on a particular project. It is difficult to enable the `auto-prop` option in all the developers machine. For the existing files, I can add the property in SVN. Is there any way I can add the property to the newly added files via hook scripts or something from server side instead of enabling `auto-prop` in all developer machines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically add svn:needs-lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711053/automatically-add-svnneeds-lock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18571763/761095.

- Force your users to use SVN 1.8 client,
- Set `svn:auto-props` to add `svn:needs-lock` on required repository items (works with Subversion 1.8+ client).

See

- [SVNBook | Inherited Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.inheritable) & [SVNBook | Automatic Property Setting](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto),
- [Subversion 1.8 Release Notes | Inherited Properties](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#iprops).

Comment: Suppose I am configuring this to set a property on all newly added *.xls files, the property will be applied  to all newly added xls files across all the repositories. I want this to happen only on a particular repository.

Comment: I am not confused with a working copy and a repository. I have more than 100 developers working across multiple projects located in different svn repositories. One developer may be working on multiple repositories at the same time. If I set 'svn:auto-props' in conf file of a developer, it will add the property independent on repository. I want the property to be added on a particular repository only. Not all the repositories that the developer works. Hope this is clear.

Comment: @DipuH what conf file? You haven't read the answer at all :/ It's about `svn:auto-props` versioned property, not about `[auto-props]` runtime configuration setting.

Comment: To be more clear, Say I have two repositories, Repo-A and Repo-B. I am working on both the repos at the same time. I want the property to be set on all *.sql files on Repo-A only. Repo-B is also having many *.sql files on which I don't want to set the property.

Comment: I am sorry. My Mistake.

Comment: It is a pain to update all the clients. In my case there are around 1400 users across the globe. Anything can be done in server side to add the property? Appreciate your patience :) Thanks

Comment: @DipuH I don't think that there is any way to do so then.