# TortoiseSVN Version 1.7.13.24257 auto needs-lock

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've viewed several questions on here where this has been asked but I can't seem to get the auto needs-lock to work. I went into the config file and added the following:

```
 * = svn:needs-lock=*
```

I also made sure that enable-auto-props was set to yes.

One thing I'm not sure about is it seems like all comments have three '#' signs in front of them and almost all other areas have one '#' sign except for the section titles such at [auto-props]. Is a single '#' a comment as well? I've tried removing it and it still doesn't seem to make a difference (including removing it on the enable-auto-props = yes line).

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried a newer TSVN version? 1.9 was just released.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically add svn:needs-lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711053/automatically-add-svnneeds-lock)