# SVN, where is config file for setting repository properties?

Tags: svn, server, locking, repository, automatic-properties

I have been researching how to set server side properties for svn repository. As described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/subversion/Inheritable-Ignores-AutoProps#Auto-Props_Hierarchy_and_Precedence), you can set repository to have something like this:
 svn:auto-props = '*.init.xml = svn:needs-lock'

The thing is, I found config file to do it for every client (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\conf), but I need to set it as a repository property. The problem is I've been searching but couldn't find neither this file in repository, nor where to place it.

You may think this is a duplicate, but:

There is a similar question-
[Automatically add svn:needs-lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711053/automatically-add-svnneeds-lock)
BUT, he as any other resource that I found doesn't say how to set it. All those resources (linked in answers as well as those that I researched myself) tell how automatic properties work, but not how to set them, unfortunately. I already tried to use svn propset command, as well as placing config file in myRepo, 
myRepo\conf, But it doesn't work.

**TLDR:** How to set svn:auto-props for repository?

Thank you very myuch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-read linked wiki-page, especially this part and below explanation for three files

> ... repository **with this hierarchy and svn:auto-props set as shown**:
>
> ```
> /                svn:auto-props = '*.bat = svn:executable'
> /ProjX           svn:auto-props = '*.c = svn:eol-style=CRLF'
>                                   '*.h = svn:eol-style=CRLF'
> /ProjY
> /ProjZ
> ```

i.e. you just `ps` on *some folder* (`^/` is OK) and all subfolders (and files in it) will inherit properties automagically